# why onCreate method runs when orientation changes each times

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I need to stop an `Activity` from going through `onCreate()` over and over again when orientation changes.

I added the following code in my `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

And added the `onConfigurationChanged()` method to the `Activity`, but it still goes through the `onCreate()` method each time the orientation changes...

Comment: In your case, why would you need to stop the Activity from being re-created?

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize` this is a nasty hack.  Please follow the advice given below.

Answer (score 5):

**This is normal/correct behavior.**

The orientation changes the layout of your `Activity`, so it's going through `onCreate()` once again (actually to let you adapt your UI to the new configuration -- portrait ain't landscape at all UI/UX wise).

**Try to never use `android:configChanges`** (from the [Android Dev Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config)); this only avoids the problem and is a bad habit.

> Note: Using (android:configChanges) should be avoided and used only as a last-resort. Please read Handling Runtime Changes for more information about how to properly handle a restart due to a configuration change.

Learn [Android lifecycles and how to save its states](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html#SavingActivityState) (to later restore it of course), by handling [runtime changes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html) the right way.

Answer (score 0):

```
    One of to stop an Activity from going through onCreate() over and over again when orientation changes, is to set Activity's Orientation 
in AndroidManifest.xml to say, "portrait" using below code.



<activity
                android:name="com.example.YourActivity"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

But this means, you are restricting Activity UI to be only supported for portrait mode which is not what user might be expecting.

And if we try with **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**, system should not recreate your Activity, excluding **keyboardHidden**.

Assuming that you are developing this your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should also declare the "**screenSize**" configuration.